# Sync issues with exchange 2010 and Outlook

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

[image: screenshot]

A lot of our users are getting these sync error. They are getting it multiple times a day and I've received thousands in a week. I've done some basic testing and it seems that people who shares calendar are getting it if the person sharing it only shared limited availability rather than full access.

Setup: 1 DAG with 2 mailbox server, 1 CAS, Edge and TMG installed on same server.

Comment: Found the fix. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982697
Stop Download shared folders fixes the problem if the users shared their calendar with limited access. Seems to be a bug, as we have the latest patches for our exchange. I've deployed the registry changes to our clients and they are no longer getting sync errors.

Comment: Ibanz, you should change your comment to an answer and answer your own question.  It is allowed and encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982697 
Stop Download shared folders fixes the problem if the users shared their calendar with limited access. Seems to be a bug, as we have the latest patches for our exchange. I've deployed the registry changes to our clients and they are no longer getting sync errors.